# Counting the number of comparisons done in Heapsort

Tags: c++, sorting, heap, priority-queue

I am trying to count the number of comparisons done by heap sorting algorithm. 
my code is based on priority queue and I want to know where I should put the counter. here is what I have but when I try to print the counter it shows zero counts, what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

here is the heapbuild  function:

```
#include<iostream>

vector<int> pq_keys;
void buildHeap()
{
int size = pq_keys.size();
int midIdx = (size -2)/2;
while (midIdx >= 0)
{      
    shiftRight(midIdx, size-1);     
    --midIdx;
}
```

and this is the function that does the comparison:

```
int shiftRight(int low, int high)
{
  int root = low;
  int counter=0;
  while ((root*2)+1 <= high)
    {
      int leftChild = (root * 2) + 1;
      int rightChild = leftChild + 1;
      int swapIdx = root;
      if (pq_keys[swapIdx] < pq_keys[leftChild])
    {
      counter++;
      cout<<counter;
      swapIdx = leftChild;

    }
    /*If right child exists check if it is less than current root*/
    if ((rightChild <= high) && (pq_keys[swapIdx] < pq_keys[rightChild]))
    {
    counter++;
    swapIdx = rightChild;    
    }
    /*Make the biggest element of root, left and right child the root*/
    if (swapIdx != root)
    { 
    counter++;
    int tmp = pq_keys[root];
    pq_keys[root] = pq_keys[swapIdx];
    pq_keys[swapIdx] = tmp;
    root = swapIdx;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}

return counter;

}
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE] .

Comment: thanks for the link but I only posted two functions, the main one which calls the function that actually compares integers and sorts them. so I don't really know what changes I can make to my question to make it more  presentable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to increment the counter *before* you do the comparison. Consider this code, from your `shiftRight` method:

```
if (pq_keys[swapIdx] < pq_keys[leftChild])
{
  counter++;
  cout<<counter;
  swapIdx = leftChild;

}
```

That only increments the counter if the conditional is true. If `pq_keys[swpIdx] >= pq_keys[leftChild]`, then you made the comparison without counting it. You need to change your code to be:

```
counter++;
if (pq_keys[swapIdx] < pq_keys[leftChild])
{
  cout<<counter;
  swapIdx = leftChild;

}
```

You need to do the same thing in the other two places where you count comparisons: increment the counter, *then* do the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
class LessPredicate 
{
  size_t callCount_ = 0;

  temlate<class T> 
  bool compare(const T& l, conct T& r)
  {
     return l < r; // or other logic
  }
public:
  size_t CallTimes() const { return callCount_; }
  temlate<class T> 
  bool operator() (const T& l, conct T& r)
  {
    ++callCount_;
    return compare(l, r);
  }
};



   int main() 
   {
     LessPredicate less;
     ...// use it like less(a, b) instead a < b;
     auto compareCount = less.CallTimes();
   }
```